# Error with building android app (cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webview

```
λ cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\yiiwe\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
null
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_a8zaoms8z5a2cue9ld42c2tqy.run(C:\Users\yiiwe\Desktop\crypt2\platforms\android\build.gradle:138)
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.564 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+.
         > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Unavailable
```

Problem started yestarday.

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml is not avaliable.

- Updating plugin cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview did't help.
- Writing variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="17+" in config.xml didn't help.
- Android Support Repository and Google Repository installed.

When I remove that plugin app is infinity loading on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `find . -name "*xwalk_core_library*"` in your project root directory.
2. Open `preview-xwalk.gradle` and replace the line `compile xwalkSpec` with `compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:VERSION'`, where `VERSION` is the version returned by command from step 1.

Example:
When I run `find . -name "*xwalk_core_library*"`, I get as a result:
`./android/.idea/libraries/xwalk_core_library_20_50_533_12.xml`

Based on that, my line in `preview-xwalk.gradle` will look like:

`compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'`

Answer (score 2):

change your gradle file inside android project *.gradle ...

in  xWALK section..

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message and fixed it by following this guide: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/server-error-with-crosswalk-when-running-ionic-run-android/104009/7